# Traffic control

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping

Good day! I am using Traffic control on ubuntu 14.04 for shaping bandwidth for rate 5Mbit/sec. After some time I would like to change the rate.

As fas as I understand I can do that with "change" command. However I am not sure how it is implemented. Since I am using TBF there are some tokens in a bucket of the buffer. If I change the rate what will be with the buffer? Does it store the tokens from the previous shaping or there will be no tokens at all right after change? Here are some example of usage:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

`tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 5Mbit latency 30ms buffer 1540
sleep 3;
tc qdisc change dev eth0 root tbf rate 8Mbit latency 30ms buffer 1540`

To my mind it may be essential if the delay between changes is small. Or I am wrong?

Thank you in advance